# Gunicorn listening always at http://127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord, webfaction

I have set up my django application on webfaction and now I am trying to move to using Guicorn to serve my application. When I set up my files and config everything seems to be working except that it is always listening at 127.0.0.1:8000.

My configuration is as below.

### supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/home/devana/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/devana/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/home/devana/webapps/devana/etc/supervisord.pid

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///home/devana/tmp/supervisor.sock
[include]
files = /home/devana/webapps/devana/etc/supervisord/*.ini
```

### Supervisor.ini

```
[program:devana]
command=/home/devana/webapps/devana/scripts/start_server
directory=/home/devana/webapps/devana/csiop/
user=devana
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /home/devana/tmp/gunicorn_supervisor.log
```

### start_server

```
NAME="devana"                                      # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/devana/webapps/devana/csiop        # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/devana/webapps/devana/run/gunicorn.sock # we will communicte using this 
                                                       unix socket
USER=devana                                        # the user to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                    # how many worker processes should     Gunicorn spawn 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=devana.settings.production  # which settings should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=devana.wsgi                     # WSGI module name
BIND=2.14.5.58:31148 (IP and the port number provided by webfaction in this place)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /home/devana/webapps/devana/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
    --name $NAME \
    --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER \
    --log-level=debug \
    --bind=$BIND
```

Now when I type the '../bin/Supervisord' command, guicorn is starting but it listening at 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of the bind variable I provided and I am not able to open my website using http://mywebsite.com.

Could someone point me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Instead of using BIND variable containing both IP and port, I separated them into two different variables and used --bind=$IP:$PORT. That seems to work

Comment: Could you not wrap the one variable as a string?

Comment: that did not work when i tried it as one string. May be i missed something else.

Answer (score 0):

If gunicon listens on `127.0.0.1:8000` it probably is the default that is applied because the supplied `-b / --bind` parameter cannot be applied.

In my case, I ran gunicorn via Docker and had the following directive in my `Dockerfile` to run as default command:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "config.wsgi", "--bind 0.0.0.0:8000"]    # listening on 127.0.0.1:8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "config.wsgi", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"] # listening on   0.0.0.0:8000
```

I'm not sure what was broken in your case but if someone from the future stumbles upon this: check how the `--bind` value is passed to gunicorn.